# Receiving strings from arduino in VS, how do I store them in a csv or xls file?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, csv, serial-port

So I'm reading strings from my arduino via serialPort, using C#.
The strings show in a text box when I do the supposed action.
What I need to do now is to put them in an array and store them at a csv or xls file.

```
    private void btRecOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)             // COMport is open                
            Text = recon;             // string recon = "recording on"
            serialPort1.Write(Text);  // sends text "recording on" to arduino
    }

    private void SerialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();            // reads data from serial port
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(trataDadoRecebido)); // calls another thread to write data in text
    }   

    private void trataDadoRecebido(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxReceber.AppendText(RxString);         
    }
```

[image: Here it goes how it shows up when I communicate with arduino]

My objective is to press the "save" button and those strings be saved in different lines of a csv or xls file.
I already tried through interop, but it gets messy! What is the best way in your opinion?

Could you give me some help or tips?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to change the textbox into a listbox. In that way you got separate string items which you can write to a file.

Another advantage of using a listbox will be that you can make a selection of items that you want to write into a file.